# Are there translations of 汉字字源字典 dictionary to english?

Tags: glyph-origin, books

If I will go here https://www.yw11.com/zidian/5416/

I will see this image from the book [**汉字字源字典**](http://www.r12345.com/ziyuan/) or **汉语字源字典** (ISBN: 9787301046791)

[image]

1. are the there translations of this book to english?
2. are there high-quality OCRed pdf? or a site with OCRed chinese text? (so that I could translate chinese to my native language)

Comment: I don't think there is an English translation, but you can purchase a hardcopy here https://book.douban.com/subject/1123885/, then scan it into text/PDF and translate using google translate.

Comment: It's actually taken from 《汉字图解字典》. I wouldn't trust it. A non-negligible portion of its entries are wrong.

Comment: @lilysirius which book / resource is better?

Comment: Try 字源 2012 compiled by 李学勤 for a good start. It's a classic and thus well proofread text version exists. There might be a copyright issue so I'm not posting links here. But it should be easy to find.

Comment: 李學勤《字源》is an OK fallback resource, but I wouldn't use it as a primary one. There's a lot of entries in there which look very outdated, and use of Simplified Chinese as the character set in a paleography text is a no-no - it's very confusing to read when they're trying to describe characters.

Answer (score 0):

There is no translation of this book. Chinese dictionaries are difficult to translate, and if translated, it is estimated that there will be more than 5,000 pages. Chinese books are very cheap. If you need ocr file, you can buy one and translate it slowly. You can but this book with $10.